# aria-sort on hyperlink instead of table thead th

Tags: html, accessibility, usability, wai-aria

I was reading/watching others implement sorting table and I haven't found any result if `aria-sort` is possible to ad on hyperlink. This is my original source code:

```
<th scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" aria-controls="data-form-table">Name</th>
```

Is this possible to use it this way?

```
<th scope="col" role="columnheader"><a href="products.php?sort=name&mode=asc" aria-sort="none" aria-controls="data-form-table">Name</a></th>
```

Comment: Why would you want to specify it on the link?

Comment: My thought was that if the user controls the sort order with the provided hyperlink all the attributes should be moved to the hyperlink.

Comment: But `aria-sort` describes what the current sort is, right? If authors could apply it to `a`, they might think that it describes to what the sort can be changed when clicking the link, I could imagine.

Comment: It make sense you are right. `aria-sort` is definitely belongs to table `th` element. Thank you guys guiding me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, but I wouldn't recommend it.

The W3C HTML validator fails anchor elements with this property.

> **Error**: Attribute `aria-sort` not allowed on element `a` at this point.

As per the WAI-ARIA 1.1 spec, authors should use `aria-sort`on the `th` element whenever possible:

> "Authors SHOULD only apply this property to table headers or grid headers."
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-sort

The caveat here is the word "SHOULD" which is defined in this context by RFC 2119:

> 3. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
>    may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>    particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>    carefully weighed before choosing a different course.
>
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119

So, while it's not *entirely* prohibited, I believe that the failure of the W3C validator is sufficient cause to believe that this may present issues with assistive technology, either now or in the future.

Comment: Thank you Josh, you helped me alot. This is indeed a little bit confusing because if you need to support non-javascript enabled functionality you have to add anchor/hyperlinks to be able to change sorting. JavaScript enabled I just hook a `click` handler to the `th` element, dynamically pull content from server, modify `aria-sort` property done. Anyway I will leave this as is also provide fallback. Thank you again.